# Scaling Apache Zookeeper Kubernetes Cluster Running on K8s

Tags: kubernetes, apache-zookeeper

I've setup a production 5 pod apache Zookeeper cluster on Kubernetes using a stateful set and PodDisruptionBudget set to 1. During testing, I noticed redeployments of the pods wouldn't always allow enough time for leader election to take place. So during scaling events sometimes the cluster would end up leaderless. So I added a sleep period before the pods were terminated and this fixed the issue.

Is there a better way of handling this on Kubernetes because my solution feels hacky?

Comment: What's your PDB? min 1?

Comment: make a readiness probe to check for zookeepers to come up and if you want to add sleep period before termination use terminationGracePeriodSeconds.

Comment: My PDB is set to maxUnavailable of 1. I've already extended the terminationGracePeriodSeconds to match the sleep trap I have set. I didn't find the readiness probe very helpful as it only checks if zookeeper is ready. The leader election is not apart of the readiness probe.

Comment: Can you provided config file of your PBD?

Comment: apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget      
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
spec:
  maxUnavailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:               
      app: zookeeper

Comment: Sorry @MaggieO couldn't get the formatting correct didn't have a ton of time to burn on it.